# Zookeeper clarification on CAP

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I would like to clarify my understanding of CAP theorem

for eg : Zookeeper is classified as CP ( Consistent and Partition Tolerant )

What does this mean ? In the event of partition failure , does the system return consistent data ?
Or does it mean that the moment there is a connectivity issue between the nodes in ZK cluster , the ZK is not available.

If yes , what it means it that , when the nodes in cluster are not able to talk to each other , the entire ZK goes down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zookeeper serves requests as long as there is quorum meaning majority of nodes are available. Since it needs majority not all the nodes its tolerant to network partition.

It replicates data to all nodes (at least the quorum) to be consistent.

If leader cannot be elected then zookeeper (no quorum) will fail requests and this is why it is not highly available.

Typically 3 or 5 servers are used for zookeeper and the quorum will be 2 or 3 nodes respectively.

Refer to this blog post for more details.
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/bd-zookeeper/index.html